# Visual studio remote server link issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Hi I am new to visual studio( currently working on VS Community) and developing a web app for a client as my project. they have given me an invitation to join visual stuido via email. So my questions are:
i) Whenever I connect to their server , the option for viewing the output in web browser changes to "Attach" amd I am not able to view the page as I would without connecting to their server.

ii) Do i have to sync SQL 2012 seperately to my visual studio for db or is it inbuilt in visual studio ?